# Should smart groups be highlighted so users are aware they are smart and so avoid corrupting them?

Tags: smartgroups

One of my users has corrupted most of their smart groups by manually adding & deleting contacts.  Talking to the user, she was not aware of what was a smart group and what was a regular group.  in fact, in normal use there is no visual difference (unless I'm missing something). However, in 'contacts/manage groups' menu option it is clearly displayed but not otherwise.
Clearly indicating that a group is smart would avoid this problem - use a different colour? I have noticed other questions about smart groups that indicate corruption caused by users manually adding contacts.  Do other users think this would be worthwhile?

Comment: This is for 4.6 but applies to all releases as far as I am aware.

Comment: We have tended to put (Smart) or similar on the end of ours, even though they are indicated as (Smart Group) in the list. For some reason we have a small number named by us as smart but that are not actually smart.

Answer (score 4):

That's a good suggestion. I've also heard the suggestion to provide an admin option to "lock" smart groups to prevent manual adding/removing of contacts.

Comment: That idea, Coleman, is a very good one. How should I go about finding how much it would cost? –

Comment: There's an issue already open about that here =] - https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17257

Answer (score 2):

What version of CiviCRM are you using Andy? I have heard the same experience from customers in the past, I think it makes sense to highlight the difference between smart groups and 'static' groups.